# bash, non-blocking stdin/console input

Tags: bash

I will like to write (using bash) something like

```
while no_user_key_pressed
{
  do_something....
}
```

There are a few options using C++, Java, ncurses and others o/s specific. I want a simple bash portable function.

<kbd>^c</kbd> interrupt should be used to kill the remaining code. Imagine something like: 'Press any key to stop test'

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: What's wrong with `^C`? are you saying I've been wrong all this time I've been using it? `;)`.

Comment: Install a signal handler that catch the `INT` ("interrupt") signal. This goes for any programming language [that knows about signals].

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf nothing wrong with ^C. is generally intended for 'cancel'. If the question is 'any key to continue', ^C should abort the script not just stop the loop.

Comment: So you want ctrl-c to be the only thing that kills the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small timeout on `read -t`.

The drawback is that the user must press < RETURN >, not "any key".

For example:

```
while ! read -t 0.01
do
    echo -en "$(date)\r"
done
echo "User pressed: $REPLY"
```

Tested on bash 3.2 (OS X)

The `!` is because `read` returns a failure (false) if the timeout expires.

Comment: Tested; works fine on latest Linux versions, fail on 2.6.18-410. 
I think that 'Press return to continue' is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can trap <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> in a way that does not kill the remaining code:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'break' INT

while true
do
    date
    sleep 1
done

echo done
$ ./test.sh 
Tue 28 Jun 12:01:22 UTC 2016
Tue 28 Jun 12:01:23 UTC 2016
Tue 28 Jun 12:01:24 UTC 2016
^Cdone
```

Comment: Excellent alternative; this is acceptable answer unless a non ^C option is available.